# Im using FullCalendar in React/JS and I need to convert a array of objects to events. The objects are improperly classified

Tags: javascript, arrays, fullcalendar

So my objects I'm fetching are ordered like this.

```
{
    "habits" : [
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "Read a book every day.",
            "description" : "I can read 20 pages in a book every day.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },

    ]
}
```

And full calendar reads arrays by looking for
`[name:,start:,daysrepeating:[this is an array of numbers 0-6]]`

I was thinking about making a constructer that takes the habits array and converts it. Do you think this is the best way? or if you know a better way please let me know.

---

Edit: i have moved on and discovered a new problem im having.

I have a json thats nothing more than an array of events.

so when loading the calendar i have the code like so

```
function HabitCalendar() {
 
    return (
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
        eventContent={renderEventContent}
        events={habits}/>
    )
  }
```

It loads the calendar but with no events :(

I keep going through all the documentation but I would really appreciate any help anyone can give.

---

The json im loading is this:

```
{
    "habits" : [
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "title" : "Read a book every day.",
            "start" : "2022-08-04",
            "description" : "I can read 20 pages in a book every day.",
            "daysOfWeek" : [0,1,2],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },
        
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Water the garden.",
            "description" : "Make sure the plants aren't thirsty.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },

        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Cardio workout.",
            "description" : "Jog a mile under 10 minutes.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },

        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "Learn how to cook something new.",
            "description" : "Eating toast and eggs every day is pretty boring.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },

        {
            "id" : 4,
            "name" : "h.",
            "description" : "some example description.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },

        {
            "id" : 5,
            "name" : "Some example habit that is very long just to test how many words I can fit in a habit name before it looks really weird.",
            "description" : "some example description.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500
        },

        {
            "id" : 6,
            "name" : "Feed the cat.",
            "description" : "You should also probably feed the cat.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "pointValue" : 500,
            "streak" : 42
        },

        {
            "id" : 7,
            "name" : "Feed the dog.",
            "description" : "Make sure the dog isn't hungry.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "streak" : 42
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 8,
            "name" : "Stop smoking.",
            "description" : "Don't inhale.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "streak" : 42
        },
        {
            "id" : 9,
            "name" : "Do a thing so that this array gets a bit longer.",
            "description" : "et's ust do a lon gtest to make sure that we can make this description really long and it still looks alright, I mean I don't expect it to be able to that's why I'm not even bothering to type well.",
            "selectedDays" : ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            "streak" : 42
        }
    ]
}
```

and the way im trying to do it is this

```
function HabitCalendar() {
 
    return (
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
        eventContent={renderEventContent}
        events={habits}/>
    )
  }
```

which loads the calendar with no events on it. I understand that the data given is not correct but right now even if I change it to just title,start it doesnt actually show anything on the calendar. And I tried using `events=JSON.Parse({Habits})` but that didnt work either.

Is this JSON not actually an array? Im sorry if I'm missing anything.

Comment: `full calendar reads arrays by looking for [name:,start:,daysrepeating`...no, fullcalendar doesn't recognise any property called "daysrepeating". https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing shows you what it recognises.

Comment: But yes if you want to use this data with fullCalendar you'll certainly need to convert it to the correct format. As for what's "best", that's entirely subjective and related to the context of your application and your purposes, both of which we know nothing about, and subjective questions are off-topic here in any case.

Comment: Yea right now the calendar is just going to display events on its own page that is loaded from json files that contain data. I dont want the user to be able to interact with it in anyway really. Right now im writing a function to loop over the array of objects and change them to what I need them to be. I was just wondering if this was a all right way to do it.

Comment: Yeah that's fine if that's what you need to do. Re your update: `I have a json thats nothing more than an array of events`...please show us that JSON which is in the `habits` variable. Is it actually JSON (i.e. a text string of data) or is it actually an real array of JavaScript objects? Fullcalendar only accepts the latter when you're providing it in this way (it accepts JSON if you give it a URL to fetch the JSON from, because it then parses it into a real array before it consumes it).

Comment: I added the array that is habits and i think your right. I think i might have to fetch this rather then just linking it but iv never worked with jsons before.

Comment: `the json im loading is this`...JSON or not, that isn't in the format fullCalendar requires - which I thought you'd already realised. Right now you have an object which _contains_ an array. You must supply _just_ the array, not within any other objects or properties. In other words, get rid of the `{
    "habits" ` at the start and the last `}` at the end, so it's just a plain array. Assuming it's an array and not a string, it should now work. If it's a JSON string, you must JSON.parse() it before you pass it to fullCalendar

Comment: @ADyson I got it :D I finished this maddness. And  you did help so thank you so much. T_T